# Directly boot Android boot partition from GRUB?

Tags: linux, boot, android, uefi, grub2

I'm experimenting with an Intel-based Android laptop (Chuwi Hi10 Pro) and have installed Ubuntu 18.04 in parallel to the original Android 5.1 installation. The device is actually designed for dual-boot with Windows 10, which I've now replaced with Ubuntu.

Problem is now that the original boot manager is unhappy with the new partitioning scheme and causes a boot loop if you don't manually select the Ubuntu entry in the initial EFI boot menu.

Since I'm booting through GRUB anyway, I've wondered if it would be possible to get rid of the original boot manager entirely and use GRUB to load the Android boot image?

Note that I think this is not a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/517212/booting-android-with-grub-but-how - I don't have Android-x86 installed, which comes with a separate kernel and initrd, but I have the original vendor Android installation, which just has a boot partition in Android bootimg format.

One option I've considered is using `abootimg` to extract standalone kernel and initrd from the bootimg dump, but I have no idea if GRUB will load the kernel image in the same way as an "official" Android bootloader, i.e. load addresses, initrd handling etc.

Any experiences?